# Undefined citations using \cite but they appear using \nocite

Tags: citing, natbib, overleaf

On Overleaf, I have some references which give an 'undefined citation error' when using \cite, but these references are cited when I use \nocite, which suggests to me that the bibliography key exists.

I have already checked that I have the correct spelling of the bib key in \cite.

I want to fix this issue because although the references get included with \nocite, the numerical citations then appear in the wrong order.

Here is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[ebook,17pt,oneside,openany]{memoir} %14 or 17 font?
%\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage{tocloft}
%\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{3em}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{soul}
%\usepackage{biblatex}
%\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\usepackage[super, numbers]{natbib} %
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\renewcommand{\bibnumfmt}[1]{#1.}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[defaultfam,light,tabular,lining]{montserrat}
\large
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{tocloft}
%\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{3em}
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\usepackage[paperheight=11in,paperwidth=8.5in]{geometry}
```

and here are the relevant entries in my bibliography:

```
  @misc{fantasyfootballscout,
  title = {\href{https://www.fantasyfootballscout.co.uk/}{\path{fantasyfootballscout.co.uk/}}}
}
 
  @misc{simon, url={https://twitter.com/analytic_fpl}, journal={Twitter}, publisher={Twitter}} 
         

   @misc{caley2015, 
     title={Premier League Projections and New Expected Goals}, url={https://cartilagefreecaptain.sbnation.com/2015/10/19/9295905/premier-league-projections-and-new-expected-goals}, 
     publisher={Cartilage Free Captain}, 
     author={Michael Caley}, 
     year={2015}, 
     month={Oct}} 


     @misc{kiwi,
     title={Calculating Finishing Skill}, url={https://jumpersforgoalposts.info/calculating-finishing-skill/}, 
     publisher={Jumpers for Goalposts}, 
     author={The FPL Kiwi}, 
     year={2021}, 
     month={Apr}}
     
  
     
          @misc{montecarlo, 
     title={Monte Carlo Method}, url={https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method}, 
     publisher={Wikipedia}, 
     author={Wikipedia}}
```

Comment: It's unlikely that you'll be able to get much help with this unless you can provide a reproducible example that people can try. Although this does not sound like an Overleaf-specific issue, if you are having trouble tracking down the source of the problem, you can reach out to Overleaf support - we'll have a look and offer suggestions. (The first suggestion will be to fix any errors that are being reported.)

Comment: Thanks, all fixed now. I fixed some other errors which I didn't realize affected these citation errors.